# the shape of $x - \frac{\lfloor q x\rfloor}{q}$ when $q \to \infty$

Tags: number-theory, farey-sequences

given an irrational $x > 0$, approximate it by a rational :
$$x = \frac{p}{q} + \epsilon$$

the residual can be seen as a function of $q \in \mathbb{N}$ :
$$\epsilon(q) = x - \frac{\lfloor q x\rfloor}{q}$$

what will be the order of the function $q \to q\,\epsilon(q)$ ? we know that 
$$\lim\inf_{q \to \infty} q \,\epsilon(q) = 0$$

because $\{a+bx \ |\ a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but can we get things like 
$$\lim\inf_{q \to \infty} \,\epsilon(q) q^k = 0$$
for some $k > 1$. apparently, as pointed out by Gerry, Dirichlet's approximation theorem says that $k = 2$ can be proven, while the [Thue–Siegel–Roth_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Siegel%E2%80%93Roth_theorem)  says that $2$ is the maximum for algebraic irrationals...

And I was also wondering if this could be related to the [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) ?

Answer (score 1):

If $\liminf f(q)=0$, then surely $\liminf f(q)/\log q=0$ as well, so maybe that's not what you meant to ask. Anyway, Dirichlet's Theorem on Diophantine Approximation says that if $x$ is irrational then there are infinitely many pairs of integers $p,q$ such that $|qx-p|<q^{-1}$, so that should give you what you want (once you figure out what you want).

Comment: no of course that was a mistake, thank you, what I want is to know how fast the lower values of $q \epsilon(q)$ tend to $0$

Comment: I'll try to understand Dirichlet's argument for $k=2$

Comment: OK, then Dirichlet gives you what you want. In general, the lower values of $|qx-p|$ are dependent on the partial quotients of the continued fraction for $x$. If, for example, the partial quotients are bounded, then you can't do any better than $Cq^{-1}$ for some $C>0$ depending on $x$. There is a lot known about this problem. "Diophantine approximation" is the search phrase.

Comment: What's $k$?${}$

Comment: I edited the message above. a number such that $\lim \inf q^k \epsilon(q) = 0$, Dirichlet says $k = 2$

Comment: Never read those https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation hope I'll understand something. and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Generalized_continued_fraction is even more intuitive that it yields a fastly converging sequence of $\epsilon(q = \prod b_i)$.

Comment: Dirichlet doesn't say $k=2$, rather, $k=2-\delta$ for any $\delta>0$.

Comment: it says the inequality
$\left|\alpha -{\frac {p}{q}}\right|<{\frac {1}{q^{2}}}$
is satisfied by infinitely many integers p and q. so you are right, it says $k=2$ but with $q^2\epsilon(q)$ converging to $1$, not to $0$.

Comment: I know what it says – I told you, remember? This implies $\liminf|qx-p|q<1$, but not $\liminf|qx-p|q=0$.

Comment: don't worry, I understood that you knew the problem and the answer, I'm impressed. studying the different cases and the different approaches https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Siegel%E2%80%93Roth_theorem#Discussion with a difference when $x$ is algebraic or transcendental looks really hard.

Comment: Yes, there are some hard open questions. No one knows exactly what happens when $x=\pi$. No one knows whether algebraic irrationals of degree 3 or greater have unbounded partial quotients.